# WPF: How to freeze column header in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview

How can I freeze my column header in a `DataGrid` in my `WPF` Window so that when I scroll down, the header is still visible.

[**Edit**]

Here's my `XAML`:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <DataGrid Name="ModelsGrid" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black"  RowHeight="30" ColumnWidth="100"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Access" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Accessibility}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Category}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[**Edit**]

I just had to get rid of the `ScrollViewer` and it's solved.

Comment: When you scroll DataGrid, column header is frozen by default (if it's just DataGrid by itself, not DataGrid in ScrollViewer). Can you show us your XAML code?

Comment: The scrollviewer was the one messing it up. Thanks @AlexButenko.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just had to get rid of the ScrollViewer and it's solved.

Comment: How does it scroll then? (I tried the same thing with a project and the DataGrid didn't scroll anymore).

Comment: Remove ScrollViewer and Add HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" in your DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

The Datagrid have [FreeColumnCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount.aspx) - set it to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: How this can be referred to the question which is about Freezing Column **Header**, not Column? Did you read the question?

Comment: For reference: FrozenColumn is for *horizontal* scrolling - it pins a number of columns to the left, and lets the rest be scrolled as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You do it with nested scroll viewers. Here's the `Template` property setter for a `Style` of `TargetType="DataGrid"`:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid">

      <DockPanel Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                      CanContentScroll="False" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                      Focusable="false" 
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

          <DockPanel Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          CanContentScroll="False" 
                          Focusable="false" 
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
              <ItemsPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
          </DockPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
      </DockPanel>

    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Of course the `ScrollViewer` can also be styled to reflect your UI design.

Answer (score -4):

it is very hard to freeze DataGrid column, Better to use DataGridView for that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/08/11/datagridviewcolumn-frozen.aspx

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, it is not hard to freeze DataGrid column in WPF.

The question is about WPF DataGrid and your link is all about WinForms. Am I missing something?