# WPF DataGrid Fixed or Sticky header on vertical scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Problem:
I am trying to make  fixed or sticky header on vertical scroll in WPF DataGrid
but I am unable to make it work
Below is the pseudo code I have

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}" x:Name="testfield"
                          SelectionMode="Extended"
                          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel">

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header1" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        ............ column data ...........
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header2" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        ............ column data 2...........
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header3" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       ................ column data 3 ...........
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>               
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF: How to freeze column header in datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208248/wpf-how-to-freeze-column-header-in-datagrid)

Comment: Please check out the comments: "Remove ScrollViewer and Add HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" in your DataGrid"

Comment: Hello nilsK, Thanks for your help on this, unfortunately this did not work, here is my updated DataGrid still the header or 1st Row scroll's away

<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount ="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BatchResults}" x:Name="batchDetailsGrid"
                              SelectionMode="Extended"
                              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

Comment: In my case scroll viewer is an inline property of DataGrid as per your suggestion I have removed them still no luck

Comment: Hello NilsK, Thanks for your support on this the previous link solved the issue, <scrollviewer> is causing that , <scrollviewer> was in the parent control that was loading my child control.. This issue can be marked as answered now

Comment: Hi Nani, glad you found a solution. To 'mark as answered" there has to be an actual answer posted to your question. If you had a different issue that needs explanation, please answer your own question and mark it as solved yourself. If not, just leave it be or delete it. - Welcome to SO btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a ScrollViewer on the parent page that was calling my child page , this was causing the entire child page to scroll that includes Headers in child page.